# Duplicated timestamps when reading data from a CSV with PySpark

Tags: python, csv, datetime, timestamp, pyspark

I want to read data from a cvs file with the following format

```
HIERARCHYELEMENTID, REFERENCETIMESTAMP, VALUE
LOUTHNMA,"2014-12-03 00:00:00.0",0.004433333289
LOUTHNMA,"2014-12-03 00:15:00.0",0.004022222182
LOUTHNMA,"2014-12-03 00:30:00.0",0.0037666666289999998
LOUTHNMA,"2014-12-03 00:45:00.0",0.003522222187
LOUTHNMA,"2014-12-03 01:00:00.0",0.0033333332999999996
```

I am using the following PySpark function to read from this file

```
# Define a specific function to load  flow data with schema
def load_flow_data(sqlContext, filename, timeFormat):

    # Columns we're interested in
    flow_columns = ['DMAID','TimeStamp', 'Value']
    df = load_data(sqlContext, filename, flow_schema, flow_columns)

    # convert type of timestamp column from string to timestamp
    col = unix_timestamp(df['TimeStamp'], timeFormat).cast("timestamp")    
    df = df.withColumn('realTimeStamp', col)

    return df
```

with the following schema and auxiliary function

```
flow_schema = StructType([
    StructField('DMAID', StringType(), True),
    StructField('TimeStamp', StringType(), True),
    StructField('Value', FloatType(), True)
])

def load_data(sqlContext, filename, schema=None, columns=None):
# If no schema is specified, then infer the schema automatically
if schema is None:
    df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv'). \
        option('header', 'true').option('inferschema', 'true'). \
        option('mode', 'DROPMALFORMED'). \
        load(filename)
else:
    df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load(filename, schema=schema)

# If no columns are specified, then select all columns
if columns is None:
    columns = schema.names
df = df.select(columns)

return df
```

I load the data from the cvs file using these commands

```
timeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS"

df_flow_DMA = load_flow_data(sqlContext, flow_file, timeFormat)
```

Then I convert this data frame to Pandas for visualisation purposes.

However, I find that `col = unix_timestamp(df['TimeStamp'], timeFormat).cast("timestamp")` is mapping different date & time strings in the cvs file (found in the field 'TimeStamp') to the same 'realTimeStamp' field, as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image]

I suspect that the problem is related to the date time string format that I am passing to `load_flow_data`; I have tried several variations but nothing seems to work.

Could someone please provide a hist at what is wrong with my code? I use Python 2.7 and Spark 1.6.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe some process is assuming the wrong time zone?

Comment: Pattern for second should be `ss` not `SS`. Uppercase `S` is for milliseconds.

Comment: Changing the pattern for seconds from `SS` to `ss` did not make any difference